# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.248.177.110:3306 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete], cpanel

Tags: mysql, node.js, linux, cpanel, web-hosting

I have a simple node app that when it starts it tries to connect to a MySQL database and pool the first user on a specific table.
This database is running on a different machine from where the node app is running.

Make Query Code

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
const config = require("config"); //config variables for enviroments

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: config.get("db.host"),
  port: 3306,
  user: config.get("db.user"),
  ssl: true,
  password: config.get("db.password"),
  database: "auth",
});

const perform = (query) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    con.query(query, function (err, result) {
      if (err) reject(new Error(err));
      resolve(result);
      con.end();
    });
  });
};

module.exports = perform;
```

calling the function when app starts.

```
perform("select * from account limit 1")
.then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
```

If i run this on my machine it works fine, connects to the database on the other machine and its able to query it without harm.

However, when I upload this code to cpanel, so I can have the node app running on my provider, and try to start the app I get the following error:

```
App Name: My Express App - Production
Listening on port 3500...
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.248.177.110:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1145:16)
    --------------------  
    at Protocol._enqueue (/<my_root_info>/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/<my_root_info>/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/<my_root_info>/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:116:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/<my_root_info>/dbQuery/performQuery.js:12:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:791:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
```

Things I have tried

I know the code works, because running the same code on my local machine gets to the database, also I tried running on yet another computer and it reached the database too.

I know the database is configured to accept external connections, the port 3306 is opened where the db is running because I can ping the address and I can connect to the database via MySQL Workbench or running the node app on any computer.

I tried to ping on cpanel's terminal the machine where the db is running (185.248.177.110) and it reaches there. But for some reason the node app cant connect to the database, when running it on cpanels terminal.

I have no idea why this is only happening on cpanels terminal, the rest of the node app works fine but the connection to the database always throws that error...

I also know that its not typo on the user or password, because those throw different errors and also I don't see any attempts being made to login on the database side.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: most server are configured only to allw access from localhist, that is why your local version works. the access from the internet is considered dangerous and so access in´s not granted to an outside ip.

Comment: thanks for the answer but i dont think you get it when i said i can access the database on my local computer. its not the same where the database is running. not the same internet not the same country even. 2 diferent machines and yet i can connect to it from my computer but i cant from cpanel, when running the node app

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out I had to ask my host provider, to make a new trafic rule for the address and port where my db was running, that is 185.248.177.110:3306.

Everything flows now.